Как в параметрах метода использовать enum метод?
namespace Mazes;

public static class EmptyMazeTask
{
    public static void MoveOut(Robot robot, int width, int height)
    {
        MoveTo12(robot, width - 2, Right);
        MoveTo12(robot, height - 2, Down);
    }
    public static void MoveTo12(Robot robot, int countSteps, way)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < countSteps; i++)
            robot.MoveTo(Direction.way);
    }
}

Нужно чтобы значения Right и Down вставали на место way

создайте Enum
public enum Direction
{
    Right,
    Down
}

затем передавайте его как тип
namespace Mazes
{
    public static class EmptyMazeTask
    {
        public static void MoveOut(Robot robot, int width, int height)
        {
            MoveTo12(robot, width - 2, Direction.Right);
            MoveTo12(robot, height - 2, Direction.Down);
        }

        public static void MoveTo12(Robot robot, int countSteps, Direction direction)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < countSteps; i++) //int=1 зачем?
            {
                robot.MoveTo(direction);
            }
        }
    }
}


Спасибо большое, очень помогли
